# VBA Combo Box Value Compile Issue

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I'm trying to add values to a Combo Box in VBA, but keep getting the below error. Any idea what I could be doing wrong? This is an ActiveX control.

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
' Add items to combobox - based off selection in DND worksheet
With Sheet1.cmbComboBox
    .AddItem "Paris"
    .AddItem "New York"
    .AddItem "London"
End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: @BigBen updated

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue - can you confirm that the actual name of your combobox is `cmbComboBox`?

Comment: @dwirony I can confirm it is "cmbComboBox"

Comment: @dwirony I have added a screenshot of the ComboBox properties

Comment: I can't repro either. A stab in the dark, but maybe close/reopen the VB Editor?

Comment: @BigBen No spaces - also closed out of Excel completely and I'm getting the same issue.

Comment: Can you confirm sheet's codename is Sheet1?

Answer (score -3):

Interestingly enough it wasn't recognizing Sheet1 as a codename for some reason. The below code seems to work.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
' Add items to combobox - based off selection in DND worksheet
With Worksheets(1).cmbComboBox
    .AddItem "Paris"
    .AddItem "New York"
    .AddItem "London"
End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Then the first worksheet's codename is not `Sheet1`.

Comment: @BigBen I am able to use Sheet1 codename to reference other objects

Comment: Hit F4 to bring up the properties pane, and stop using the defaults! Call that sheet `CountriesSheet` and stop using `Sheet1`, especially if you don't know what sheet `Sheet1` is a code name for! The code name is the `(Name)` property - the first in the list.

Comment: But can you confirm (via a screenshot perhaps) that the *first* sheet's codename is in fact `Sheet1`? If that code snippet works, then the first worksheet's codename is something else, not `Sheet1` (and this has been a wild goose chase(

Comment: @BigBen attached a screenshot to the above answer

Comment: The point is that you're using the *wrong* code name. The solution is to use the *correct* code name, not to switch to index-based dereferencing. `Worksheets(1)` will break as soon as a user moves that sheet anywhere else, and `Worksheets("Sheet1")` will break as soon as a user renames that sheet. Codenames can't get tampered with by users.

Comment: @BigBen all that tiny picture proves, is that the `Sheet1` identifier is legal (and we already knew that, otherwise `Option Explicit` would have barked). It doesn't mean that's where the combobox is.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon - yep. Which is why I have to downvote this answer.

Comment: Huh... interesting then... is the combobox really on that sheet? That is the only way i can reproduce the error.

Answer (score -4):

Very simple fix, you can't reference the worksheet named "Sheet1", just by putting Sheet1, unless you set "Sheet1" to the variable Sheet1.   Not very good code.
Just reference the worksheet the usual way.... Sheets("sheet1") or if you know its code name or it's index, etc.......

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
' Add items to combobox - based off selection in DND worksheet
With Sheets("Sheet1").cmbComboBox
    .AddItem "Paris"
    .AddItem "New York"
    .AddItem "London"
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: No, this is not correct. `Sheet1` references the sheet's code name.

Comment: `Sheet1` *is* the codename. It's actually *very* good code :-) And if it weren't the code name, it would be a different error message entirely. Well actually `Option Explicit` would flag an undeclared variable.

Comment: How do you know it's the code name.   Did I mess that in the question(s)?

Comment: `Sheet1` is the default code name for the first-created worksheet of a workbook on any English-language system. Best practice would be to give it an actual meaningful name, but seeing `Sheet1` undeclared in code is 99.99% certain to be it - here since the compiler isn't complaining about the identfiier, the certainty is 100% thanks to `Option Explicit` =)

Comment: Well I didn't assume.   But it could be that there is no combobox on the codenamed sheet1 worksheet, because that is the exact error I get if there is no combobox.

Comment: [Correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60382921/vba-combo-box-value-compile-issue#comment106817718_60383338)

Comment: So, actually, my answer is correct by not assuming the combobox was on codename Sheet1.

Comment: Claiming `Sheet1` is not very code is not correct IMO.... In that case the answer should be "Use the right code name" - or this question should just be closed.

Comment: That part is correct, yes - the part that ignores the existence of worksheet code names and deems it "not very good code", much less so. If this code works, it's more fragile than what the OP had in the first place, because it's now dependent on an index (/name) rather than a programmatic identifier.